# SEO - Search result listing shows up in a foreign language

Tags: seo, google-search, dns

Yesterday I moved our company's Wordpress site to a new server. Not long after, and perhaps only coincidentally, the search result for that site in Google started showing up with a Japanese name and description.

I checked that our metadata was not in Japanese (no idea why it would be, but we had just migrated and things happen). I wasn't able to get much further than that before I went home for the day, intending to pick up the search in the morning. However, when I got in today, I found that the problem had corrected itself - our listing was back to English.

The issue is fixed now, with no help from me, so it must have been on Google's side. Still, I have no idea why this would have happened beyond maybe some weird DNS propagation issue. Most of our traffic is in the US, so overseas DNS probably picked up our new IP faster because they wouldn't have it cached. Maybe that has something to do with it?

I couldn't find any record of this happening to other sites. I am now really curious... what might have been going on for the brief span of time when we became world travelers?

Comment: I guess the question is why this may have happened? You are probably right about DNS, coincidences, and so forth. Google does also make odd mistakes now days. It could even be a Loo Loo (southern slang for spirit or ghost).